# Is it possible to have someone assist with Android problems via remote assistance?

Tags: remote-access

I have too many problems to mention including the truth about what my phone model/details 'really' are. I've got a few programs downloaded on my laptop due to the many issues I have with my Android, but I've had various different 'specs' come back to mere my model details, etc. (I am probably classed as under novice level by the way and I really would rather not be told off for fiddling where I shouldn't as I have, sadly, learnt that already the very hard/frustrating way)

These versions are:

1. Alps MTK MTK6577 (e1909l_v77_gq1008_a41_v20) on Android 4.1.1 JellyBean
2. Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (SM N900A) on Android 4.4.2 (build KOT49H_N900aAUCUCMLG)
3. STAR N9770 I9220 Pad
4. HTC MT6577

I downloaded these prog's because my phone constantly said no memory yet the phone's internal storage was empty. Due to too much internet info making stuff sound less complicated than reality, I went down the rooting my phone path and now it's worse than before(ish).

Much more to divulge but I'd like to know the answer to my simple query before writing my thesis.

Comment: Are you asking of something like AA or Teamviewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is **yes**. You can use [Teamviewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market&hl=en)    for an example.
Just look up Android Remote Assistance on the play store and you will find multiple options.